# How to access a resource file that's not in the root of the Resources folder? (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, resource-files

I followed [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnwpowell/archive/2009/11/29/sharepoint-2010-localization-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx) tutorial to create a resource file named `GlobalResources.resx` under `Resources`.

[image: Resources file in root]

I am able to access the content of the resource file using:

```
string resourceVal = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:GlobalResources, ResourceKey", "GlobalResources", language);
```

However, to follow company coding standards, I am required to move the resources file into a folder named `<client>.<department>.<project>.<farm|sandbox>`.
So I did this:

[image: Resource file in sub-folder]

But now I'm not able access the resource values!

I tried the following...

(a)

```
SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm/GlobalResources, ResourceKey", "Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm/GlobalResources", language);
```

(b)

```
SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm\\GlobalResources, ResourceKey", "Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm\\GlobalResources", language);
```

(c)

```
SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm.GlobalResources, ResourceKey", "Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm.GlobalResources", language);
```

...but none of them worked.

***How do I access the resource file that's not in the root of the*** `Resources` ***folder?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received an answer to this question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85792/how-to-specify-the-complete-path-for-a-resource-file-when-accessing-it-in-sharep).

This worked:

```
string resourceVal = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:ResourceKey",
"Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm\\GlobalResources", language);
```